# I cant get strip() to successfully remove single quotes from an IP address

Tags: python

This is a script for basically pulling an IP address from a source path on our router. I can successfully pull the IP address and subnet, but for some reason I can't figure out how to remove the single quotes and leave the doubles.

```
source_path = []
if item["sourcePath"] == "":
    source_ranges = None
else:
    for source in item["sourcePath"].split(","):
        thing = '"%s"'.strip(chr(39)) % "".join(("",source,""))
        source_path.append(thing)
```

I'm attempting to remove the single quotes from a value when it is returned, but instead what I end up getting is this: '"10.0.0.1/25"'

I've tried using strip() in various forms here to achieve this value: "10.0.0.1/25" without single quotes. I've also tried adding these other 3 methods:

```
thing = '"%s"' % "".join(("",source,"")).strip(chr(39))
thing = '"%s"' % "".join(("",source,"")).strip('')
thing = '"%s"'.replace("'", "") % "".join(("",source,""))
```

However, nothing changes and I still get the double quotes. This script simply pulls IP addresses from a JSON file and then converts them into YAML, thus the need for double quotes instead of single. What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us a sufficiently complete [mre] so we know _how_ you're determining your data to contain literal double quotes. (We should be able to run the code just by copying and pasting an entire block with no other changes).

Comment: Note that in general, the worry about single-vs-double quotes isn't something you should be involved in at all -- the YAML library you're using is responsible for quoting data as correct YAML; you shouldn't be worrying about that yourself. (If you aren't using a YAML library, that's a bigger problem). Bottom line: Your strings should just be regular Python strings with no literal quotes at all. The serialization/deserialization tools should be responsible for managing quoting and escaping.

Comment: (This also means that what kind of quotes Python's `repr()` uses is of no consequence, since those are _syntactic_ quotes and not _literal_ ones -- they're part of the display, not part of the data).

Comment: Does `'"%s"' % source.strip("'")` do what you want?

Comment: Does ```"'10.0.0.1/25'".replace('\'','')``` work?

Answer (score 0):

`'"foo"'` is Python's `repr()`esentation of the string `"foo"`. The single quotes are not in the string, so you can't remove them. They're a problem, instead, with *how you're printing* the string.

`print(yourstring)` will not have these quotes. `print(repr(yourstring))` will.

Whereas if you're passing your data to a YAML library, *there shouldn't be any literal quotes in it at all*. Your literal data (as opposed to the syntax used to represent that data) should just be `foo`, not `"foo"` or `'foo'`.